# angular-oauth2-oidc - Read user claims

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, oauth, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using `angular-oauth2-oidc`'s Code Flow  in an Angular application. It's working all good, however I cannot read the user claims.

I tried using `this.oAuthService.getIdToken()`, `this.oAuthService.getAccessToken()`, `this.oauthService.getUserInfo()` but I don't seem to get any valid JWT that can be decoded using regular methods.

In my backend API (.NET Core) I use the `access_token` to query the TokenIntrospection endpoint and I can see all the claims properly.

Relevant info:

```
export const oAuthConfig: AuthConfig = {
  issuer: environment.oauth.issuer,
  // URL of the SPA to be redirected to after login
  redirectUri: environment.oauth.redirectUri,
  clientId: environment.oauth.clientId,
  dummyClientSecret: environment.oauth.clientSecret,
  responseType: 'code',
  scope: 'openid profile email',
  showDebugInformation: true,
  oidc: true,
  requireHttps: false,
};
```

```
async login() {
  await this.oAuthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin();
  await this.oAuthService.initCodeFlow();

  this.router.navigate(['/']);
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `getIdentityClaims` method that will give you id_token claims as an object. First though you need to check the HTTP requests to verify that an id_token is actually being returned, and that it contains the claims you expect.

**CLAIMS ISSUING TO TOKENS**

In an Authorization Server you can specify where claims are issued to and it is very standard to issue different claims to the two tokens:

- In your case an ID token is for use by a UI client and may contain details such as a name for display
- An access token is issued for use by an API client and might contain a role or user id used for authorization.

To better understand this concept, see the [Claims Mapper](https://curity.io/resources/videos/claims-mapper/) concept used by the Curity Identity Server.

I suspect in your case the system is not configured to (or does not support) issuing some claims to the id token.

**MY PREFERENCE**

I actually think you are on the right track with your access token handling. Another way for a UI to get user info is to send the access token to its API, at a path such as **/api/userinfo/current**, and the API can then return a JSON object containing:

- Claims from the access token
- Any other domain specific data that may be useful to the UI

This design has the following benefits:

- Extensibility: it is easy to add extra data to the API payload, which may have nothing to do with OAuth
- Privacy: adding too much user data to an id_token is often not recommended, since it is then available in a viewable JWT which lasts for an entire user session

Comment: Hey Gary.. thanks for the help! I am indeed getting the id_token (which is a valid/readable JWT), however some claims are missing (like username), even though I get them when I use the token introspection endpoint from the API.. is that expected or am I missing something? Also, similarly to what you proposed, I created a /auth/claims endpoint to return the user claims..

Comment: got it.. they are basically customizable on a per-environment setting.. thank you!